# What is this bushy plant with narrow leaves and white flowers?

Tags: identification, flowers, shrubs

Can someone please help me identify this bushy plant? It has narrow grey/greem leaves and white flowers. It was found in the Calgary region.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way you could post a few more pictures?  My guess is Candy Tuff or Iberis (sempervirens)...are these leaves a true grey green or is this a white powdery mildew?  Need close ups and how tall does this plant grow? I peeked at the next page...is that YOUR baby girl? Way too wonderful of a picture, oh my gosh!

Answer (score 2):

This was my initial thought, Pearly Everlasting.  One of the best white flowers to dry and use in dried flower arrangements.  All I could remember was pearly and anaph...it just came to me as I do know this plant.  Another picture or two would be necessary to ID but I am so excited that I finally remembered the name I am sending it as an answer. [Anaphalis margaritacea](https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=pearly%20everlasting%20(anaphalis%20margaritacea))